# Regressing/interpolating between quasi-periodic sinusoids

Tags: fourier-transform, frequency, interpolation

This is a [cross-post (on recommendation) from CV](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/251304/choosing-kernel-for-gaussian-process-regression-kriging-with-strong-directiona).

My problem is very simple.

I currently intend on using Kriging (Gaussian process regression) to perform regression between the trajectories marked with red dots on the below plot, where a simple linear-regression surface has been superimposed as well.

As you can see there is a strong correlation in a particular direction of the four time-series.

[image]

Through long and very interestind discussion with @DeltaIV, we started consdering other methods such as harmonic regression. The latter would have been very elegant except the example time-series in the above plot have different periods (fundamental frequencies) thus HR will not work.

Hence I would like to ask you excellent people what you would recommend for either regression or interpolation between quasi-periodic time-series such as the above? I should not that the above plot shows only one period, that approximately repeats itself but not quite (hence 'quasi').

Alas currently (in order of preference):

- Multivariate splines (recommendations here welcome too)
- Gaussian process regression (with complex kernel choice)
- Some magical way of making harmonic regression work with time-series with different periodicity

**UPDATE:**

Here is another image, showing the periodicity of ONE of the signals annotated by the red dots above. Thus, this time-series shows the periodicity of the time-series over a longer period of recorded time. Again, this is just ONE of the above four time-series, recorded at a certain regime.

[image]

Comment: So, as far as I understood, you know that each time series is highly periodic, right? But: you can't compare things at fixed time offsets, because the period is different for every realization. Would estimating that period and then normalizing to a *phase* (i.e. $\frac{\text{sample time}}{\text{Period}}$) be an option?

Comment: @Marcus could you give an example? Your description is correct regarding the problem. Though I do not quite understand your proposal.

Comment: Assume that you were able to measure the frequency of the periodic signal. Since we can assume sufficient bandwidth limitation (you've sampled the signal, after all), it's possible to resample the signals in a manner that brings them all to the same frequency (measured in $f_\text{sample}$)  and thus, making the resulting samples comparable

Comment: I think I understand what you mean; thus using a first sampled signal as a basis function almost, we can measure the rest of the sampled signals in terms of this base?

Comment: First, i should confirm that the thousands axis are time, and the decimal axis is space? Though this could be viable, i fail to see a periodical behaviour on any section, hence i cannot suggest any periodic strategy on that sense. Unless you clarify us which is the physical meaning of the measurements?. Also, using dynamical system techniques for the time axis is a way better approach than kernels. If and only if we can plug in causality on the estimation...... Can you paste another clearer image of what we should achieve? Or the physical meaning of all this? At least, the meaning of the axes

Comment: @hypfco please let me explain, and if it still is not clear then I shall post another image to better explain it. A) Yes the axis in the magnitude in thousand is evolving in time, this is ONE period of FOUR sinusoidal waves (from which we have samples indicated by the red dots). Hence, the periodicity comes in because each of the dotted signals repeat themselves, thus making this a periodic time-series problem (or at least quasi periodic).

Comment: The physical meaning: each dotted time-series represents a measure of the same angle at a different velocity (measured by the axis from 0.8 to 1.6), and the dots show samples of that temporal evolution (for ONE period) of that angle, at different velocities. Measuring the angle for a longer amount of time would result in a periodic time-series.

Comment: What we want to achieve: I want a good estimate by way of regression or interpolation, of what is happening in between the sampled curves (marked with red dots), for velocities that I, for practical reasons, cannot measure on my system.

Comment: Yeah, post several images, and your papers if needed. Nobody is in here for stealing other's algorithms. I can assure that :).

Comment: @hypfco - so the above was not clear? :(

Comment: You made me curious so now you have to satisfy that curiosity. I am not seeing the transient in the picture. I want to see if the system has dynamic on time.

Comment: So this is a kind a wheel, and encoder, a tracking device?. I am thinking seriously you are representing the wrong variables. Kriging is good for spatial estimation, but when a dynamic is in there, the Kriging is ignoring all that information.

Comment: It is actually just a lever which when actuated, creates this change in angle, with respect to its base (so the angle is just the angle between the base and the lever). The angle evolution changes with, with changes in actuation regime (i.e. in this case velocity).

Comment: I may well be representing the wrong thing; that's why I am asking for help :) Also I have now added a new image.

Comment: Yeah, this is a chaotic system. You can define states and draw state space curves and pretend with them. But this is still a dynamic system. Do you only measure the output? Is there an input voltage to the actuator? Is there a controller loop?. Do you know that the relation between the actuator input and the output is almost trivial?

Comment: The input is nothing we can measure for lots of boring reasons. Nor do we have access to the control loop either. Basically that is all black box (actually for sake of argument, lets just assume it is the angle of a human arm to the human body), but we know that the system behaves like the above images show, at various velocities. And I just want to regress these curves between the velocities, to see what the curves would look like at new velocities which I can not measure, thus yielding some sort of good estimate.

Comment: That is the proper way for dealing with such systems. That is how you solve this. The curve you are having is just the output of the controller, plus some really basic dynamic (the lever plus a mass plus the actuator response). Because you dont have the input, you now have to "guess" what the black box outputs to you.

Comment: IF you want to show something decent to the people, you can apply most of the state space techniques -Lorentz Attractor, Poincare Sections, etc.etc.- for guessing which is the current state based on some few variables. I suggest you to define such orbits, and identify probability intervals under those sections, so you can draw an estimate based on that, which in your paper will look decent. Just take 100 cycles, and draw the orbits.

Comment: So the proper way of dealing with this is chaos theory? Hmm... ok. Any links you can suggest to get started with (I have never touched chaos theory before) in relation to what I would like to achieve (which you have a rather intimate understanding of now :)

Comment: Quasi periodic systems is the same than chaotic systems, with all the techniques you have in there. If you do some spline you will have a good guess. But it will not be the proper way. The proper way in here is defining the state space orbits.

Comment: I just don't understand how I would guess the current state though (I believe we mean the same thing when I say that; the time-period at a certain velocity), since I have no information of any variables other than the velocity I want the time-period for.

Comment: State space orbits... ok. Cool. Any example at all you could give that is relevant to this problem would be very kind. I am not quite sure where to start.

Comment: The simplest choice is taking $\theta$ and $d\theta/dt$. This is normally done with truly quasi stable systems, indeed not for systems with controller for analyzyng a controller, but you will have an orbit. Based on that you can define a phase, and based on the orbits and the phase you have an estimate for the angle. With that in hand, you can return to your 3D plot, and do the same. Just make a plot of $\theta$ vs $d\theta/dt$ vs $v$. Dont read anything more. The more compact is the section, the better the estimate.

Comment: Right.. not entirely sure what to search for in terms of a guiding example, perhaps "Lorentz attractor for time-series" ?

Comment: @hypfco this would be a really good place for a meme. I still only have $\theta$ for four $v$:s, and the same for $d \theta / d t$ - I truly do not understand how I am to estimate $\theta$ and $d\theta / d t$ outside my known domain of $v$ (where I have data at four velocities). Using chaos theory.

Comment: We really ran out of possibilities.

Comment: @hypfco no idea what that means.

Comment: My friend, you are not helping us in helping you in being commited to find a solution. I cannot find a robust algorithm if you dont collaborate and seek the information, you cannot just say "this is a blackbox, you have to solve it as is". Actually, you are in charge of finding the solution and providing all required information and data. Without that, we are losting our time here.

Comment: Oh right, I did not mean to offend, I truly appreciate your help and advice and I believe I have given an accurate description of my system? But I have zero experience on chaos theory, thus I do not even know where to start, hence I merely wanted a guiding light for what keyword to put into Google. I'll take it from there afterwards.